# Change the value of a button in jquery.validate

Tags: jquery-validate

I have an aspnet form which I am validating using jquery-validate. 
In the form there is a photo upload button. jquery-validate changes the value of this button from 'Upload' to 'Next'. Is it possible to prevent this e.g. add a rule that sets the value of this button, thus overriding jquery-validate's renaming of the button? See example below:

I am new to SO and fairly new to jQuery. Any help mucho abrigado.

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphContent$btnUpload" value="Upload" onclick="return checkFile();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(..)" id="ctl00_cphContent_btnUpload" class="button bt-upload ">

    $("#aspnetForm").formwizard({ //form wizard
        formPluginEnabled: true,
        validationEnabled: true,
        focusFirstInput: true,
        validationOptions : { //validation rules
            debug:true,
            errorElement: "span",
            rules: {
                ctl00$cphContent$btnUpload:{value:"Upload"}
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Since we're talking about JavaScript which only runs in the browser, show the code output.  In other words, where is the HTML and JavaScript as _rendered_ in the browser?

Comment: @Sparky If you down voted my question because I didn't post code in the question, perhaps you could retract your down vote since I have edited the question. Trying to get reputation points is not easy with such a tough crowd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I created a 'fakebutton' and hid the original Upload button and then added

```
$('#fakeupload').click(function(){
    $('#ctl00_cphContent_btnUpload').trigger('click');
});
```

It's not pretty but it works.